# How does socketio filter events (specifically flask-socketio)

Tags: http, optimization, websocket, socket.io, flask-socketio

**Background**

Suppose there are N clients and N nodes, each node emits a message that contains statistics and it's name . A single client n ∈ N only cares about a specific node n ∈ N.

**Proposed Solution**

Each client listens to a specific event *node_name*, when the server receives a message from a node with it's *node_name*, emit an event *node_name*

**Question**

When an event is emitted *node_name*,

will the message be sent to every client n ∈ N and then be thrown away if there is no listener for that specific *node_name*

OR

does the server keep meta data and knows which clients/connections are listening for the event *node_name* and only send to the specific client n

**Modifications**

Can the latter be achieved through namespaces

OR

Would it be advisable to create a room for each node ? Would these rooms act as the meta data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Events are filtered at the client level, while namespace and rooms are at the server level

All connected clients within the same namespace and room are sent all events

Looking within the source for we see that flask_socketio provides a layer on top of socketio which contains some wrapper functions in it's `__init__.py` which calls functions from instantiated properties of it's core files.

The `emit` function from `base_manager.py` is as such

```
    def emit(self, event, data, namespace, room=None, skip_sid=None,
         callback=None, **kwargs):
    """Emit a message to a single client, a room, or all the clients
    connected to the namespace."""
    if namespace not in self.rooms or room not in self.rooms[namespace]:
        return
    for sid in self.get_participants(namespace, room):
        if sid != skip_sid:
            if callback is not None:
                id = self._generate_ack_id(sid, namespace, callback)
            else:
                id = None
            self.server._emit_internal(sid, event, data, namespace, id)
```

It uses a function called `get_participants` which looks as such

```
def get_participants(self, namespace, room):
    """Return an iterable with the active participants in a room."""
    for sid, active in six.iteritems(self.rooms[namespace][room].copy()):
        yield sid
```

Finally a look at the function `enter_room` reveals the structure of the object that stores client hierarchy

```
def enter_room(self, sid, namespace, room):
    """Add a client to a room."""
    if namespace not in self.rooms:
        self.rooms[namespace] = {}
    if room not in self.rooms[namespace]:
        self.rooms[namespace][room] = {}
    self.rooms[namespace][room][sid] = True
```

Given the structure, it would be best to use *node_name* as the name of the room under a specific predefined namespace.

Comment: Yes. If you want to do pub/sub type things, then rooms is the best approach.